# How to add a Build modifier Object from Blender 2.82 into Unity 2017.12?

Tags: modifiers, export

I have trouble in exporting to Unity

I wanted to use *Build* modifier to showing up in Unity animation

The object I use is a truss from "archipack"

First I try exporting FBX into unity as usual which will work perfectly with physic simmulation or keyfframed mesh animation but the result is the *Build* modifier won't effect the mesh, it just stand there without any animation.

I didn't applied the build modifier while exporting otherwise it will be stuck at that visual frame. I want all those animation to be imported.

Second I read something on trying to export to MMD first and re import it into Blender but this thing show up and I can't continue.

````
------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons\io_shape_mdd\__init__.py", line 152, in execute
    return export_mdd.save(context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons\io_shape_mdd\export_mdd.py", line 110, in save
    check_vertcount(me, numverts)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons\io_shape_mdd\export_mdd.py", line 51, in check_vertcount
    raise Exception('Error, number of verts has changed during animation, cannot export')
Exception: Error, number of verts has changed during animation, cannot export

location: <unknown location>:-1


-----
```
````